# meaning of model.parameters LIBSVM

Tags: libsvm

I am using libsvm on MATLAB. the model-struct has a field named "parameters" which contains 5 values. what is the meaning of each? in which field do I find the parameters 'c' and 'gamma' which were used for the radial basis kernel?

Answer (score 2):

libsvm's code is hard to read, but I think you need to take a look at `matlab/svm_model_matlab.c`. There, you will see the following:

```
ptr[0] = model->param.svm_type;
ptr[1] = model->param.kernel_type;
ptr[2] = model->param.degree;
ptr[3] = model->param.gamma;
ptr[4] = model->param.coef0;
```

So I expect that that the 4th and 5th values from your "parameters" field will contain `gamma` and `C` (indexes in C start from 0, while, in Matlab, they start from 1).

I haven't tested this out, but I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I explicitly trained a model to see the parameters.
Using below code in Matlab, I set the parameters.

```
model = svmtrain(train_l, traindata,['-s 0 -t 3 -c 20 -g 0.0007 ']);
```

The parameters are listed below.

```
model.Parameters                                                    

ans =

     0
3.0000
3.0000
0.0007
     0
```

As you can see and I tested multiple times, the parameter C is on this list. The 3rd is the degree which is 3 by default, the 4th is gamma.